# Remove fragments between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can anyone suggest the way to remove fragments between two fragments.
I have stack like Frag1 -> Frag2 -> Frag3 -> Frag4 , Now if i press back From Frag4  i want to land on Frag1.

Answer (score 2):

On destroy of the `Fragment` `Frag4` clear `Back Stack` up to `Frag2`.
Try something like this:

`public` method in your `MainActivity`:

```
public void clearBackStackInclusive(String tag) {
     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

now in your `Frag4` fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   ((MainActivity)getActivity()).clearBackStackInclusive("tag"); // tag (addToBackStack tag) should be the same which was used while transacting the Frag2 fragment
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#popBackStack(java.lang.String,%20int))